# App crashes when I attempt to have a dynamic value in spinner

Tags: firebase, dictionary, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, spinner

I have the following code and was wondering why it crashes the app, I was hoping you could help me figure out what was going on.

The code below is not exact aside from the spinner code.

The idea is to have the spinner racePicker's array populated by FireStore document IDs, as shown below:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

val raceArray = ArrayList()
raceArray.add("Select race...")

db.collection("races").get().addOnSuccessListener { 
DocumentSnapshot ->
    for (document in DocumentSnapshot) {
        raceArray.add(document.id)
        Log.e("info", "raceArray contains values $raceArray")
    }
```

This is a rough approximation. I may have set it .toString() or maybe used .addAll vs .add in the raceArray statement.

(I honestly don't remember exactly if this is how I coded it, but it's close enough to give an idea, I'm typing from memory at the moment).

My intention was to use it like so:

```
racPicker.onSelectedItemListener = object : 
OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNothingSelected() {
        }
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: 
View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
val selection = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
    when (selection) {
        "$selection" -> raceArray.remove("Select race...").also{ 
statAllocator(selection) }
    }
}
}
```

For some reason it crashes, but if I assign a literal such as "race name" -> fun, "2nd race name" -> fun, etc it works.

Would it be better to use

```
if (selectedItem.equals("$selection") {
        // do stufd
    }
```

instead? Or is it absolutely necessary to call each and every when case/statement as a literal string? I essentially am looking for a way to have the spinner's selected item (which is an array of document names generated from FireStore database) then "check for itself" and trigger the other functions.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.